# HTML5: Apply transparency to Canvas after drawing through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm attempting to draw multiple objects to a canvas element, and then fade them out cleanly. However, when attempting to use globalAlpha to achieve this, you can see pieces of objects that would normally be obscured, as each object becomes individually transparent. To explain:

Consider the following code:

```
context.fillStyle="yellow";
context.fillRect(0,0,100,100);
context.fillStyle="blue";
context.fillRect(50,50,100,100);
```

This will create an image like this:

```
Y = Yellow, B = Blue

Y Y Y Y
Y Y Y Y
Y Y B B B B
Y Y B B B B
    B B B B
    B B B B
```

The blue box completely covers the yellow box, as desired. However, when we start to add transparency into the mix:

```
context.globalAlpha=0.5;
context.fillStyle="yellow";
context.fillRect(0,0,100,100);
context.fillStyle="blue";
context.fillRect(50,50,100,100);
```

We end up with this:

```
Y = Yellow, B = Blue, M = Mix of both

Y Y Y Y
Y Y Y Y
Y Y M M B B
Y Y M M B B
    B B B B
    B B B B
```

Because the blue rectangle is transparent when it's being drawn, the corner of the yellow box that was previously obscured is now visible. And that's just ugly.

Keep in mind: both the canvas that's being faded out and the elements behind it are a complicated, dynamic mess; manually tracking every object that's being drawn and how they overlap would get out of control very quickly, and it's likewise not a viable solution to use a solid-color overlay to "fake" a fade out.

While I'm open to using CSS transparency to achieve this if it's really the best way to go, I'm hoping to accomplish this using canvas itself. I've come across [canvas pixel manipulation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas), which might be an option, but I'm concerned I might be overlooking a much simpler, efficient way of handling this.

Any ideas?

Comment: What makes you think using CSS opacity is inferior in some way?

Comment: So you're looking for the now-discontinued [Crayola Overwriters](https://www.google.com/search?q=crayola%20overwriters&rct=j) HTML5 Canvas equivalent?

Comment: would that be a match ? http://jsbin.com/sizupidipu/1/edit

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To have a clear effect that will fade out the current canvas, you can use the 'destination-out'  operation when completely filling with any color : this leaves the canvas untouched... Unless you lower the globalAlpha to x, then the resulting alpha will be multiplied by 1-x.

(http://dev.w3.org/fxtf/compositing-1/#porterduffcompositingoperators_srcout )

jsbin :

http://jsbin.com/cecavojepa/1/edit?js,output

core fading function :

```
function fadeCanvas() {
  ctx.save();
  ctx.globalAlpha = 0.1;
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation='destination-out';
  ctx.fillStyle= '#FFF';
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,cv.width, cv.height);    
  ctx.restore();   
}
```

Comment: interesting however it does not completely fade out when you use strokeRect instead with a black stroke!

Answer (score 0):

I think that the easiest solution is going to be just using CSS opacity:

```
#mycanvas {opacity: 0.5}
```

One line, no mess.

Answer (score 0):

I feel a bit silly for answering my own question, but in trying to explain why I wanted to avoid CSS--because a pure canvas solution would also allow combining multiple canvases into one--I realized the solution was staring me right in the face:

Render the flat version offscreen, then draw the resulting image to the onscreen canvas using the desired transparency.

Example code:

```
// Create an offscreen canvas large enough to fit our drawing
var offscreenCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
offscreenCanvas.height = 150;
offscreenCanvas.width = 150;

// Draw to the offscreen canvas
var offscreenContext = offscreenCanvas.getContext("2d");
offscreenContext.fillStyle="green";
offscreenContext.fillRect(0,0,100,100);
offscreenContext.fillStyle="blue";
offscreenContext.fillRect(50,50,100,100);

// Draw our offscreen canvas to our visible canvas as an image
visibleContext.globalAlpha=0.3;
visibleContext.drawImage(offscreenCanvas, 0, 0);
```

This prevents the "mixing" of colors from multiple overlapping objects, allowing for much cleaner looking fade-in/fade-out effects.

Comment: it's way faster to draw on the displayed canvas, then to fillRect in either black or white to fade out. http://jsbin.com/sizupidipu/2/edit

Comment: @GameAlchemist That solution creates a "fade-to-<color>" effect, whereas the goal here is to create a "fade-out" effect. As noted in the question, what's visible behind the canvas object is not simply a solid color, but a dynamic image all of its own.

Comment: Ok, i was wondering. Then that's just a matter of choosing the right composite mode. Destination-out seems a fit candidate : http://jsbin.com/sizupidipu/4/edit?js,output  (way faster than drawImage an offscreen canvas)

Comment: That also seems like a viable solution. I'll probably try putting together a JSPerf to test which is faster and by how much, but I suspect you're correct to say that destination-out would be faster.

Comment: No need to benchmark : fillrect is faster than drawImage. And with an offscreen canvas, you take the risk that it wouldn't be hardware accelerated on some devices/browsers.