# How to fully fade out contents in canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

This question has been asked twice *without* the caveat of ***"Fully Fade Out"***

- [Fastest way of fading out entire contents of a canvas to transparency, not other color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52878641/fastest-way-of-fading-out-entire-contents-of-a-canvas-to-transparency-not-other)
- [HTML5: Apply transparency to Canvas after drawing through JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27082720/html5-apply-transparency-to-canvas-after-drawing-through-javascript)

Both of the accepted answers only partially fade out the contents.  They both suggest something like:

```
// semi functional code, but doesn't fully work
ctx.save();
ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-in";
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9)";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
ctx.restore();
```

This leaves residue everywhere, never fully fading out anything.  See example below:

```js
let canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let rand = n => Math.floor(Math.random() * n);
setInterval(() => {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(rand(300), rand(120), rand(60), Math.PI * 2, 0);
  ctx.fillStyle = `rgba(${rand(256)}, ${rand(256)}, ${rand(256)}, 1)`;
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
  ctx.fill();
}, 1000);

let fadeOut = () => {
  let fadeAmount = 0.05;
  // Note that the colour here doesn't matter! Only the alpha matters.
  // The colour here is red, but you'll see no red appear
  ctx.fillStyle = `rgba(255, 0, 0, ${1 - fadeAmount})`;
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-in';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 120);
  requestAnimationFrame(fadeOut);
};
requestAnimationFrame(fadeOut);
```

```css
canvas { border: 3px solid #808080; background-color: #000000; }
```

```html
<canvas width="300" height="120"></canvas>
```

---

The question is:  **How can one *fully* fade out elements on a canvas, all the way to transparent?**

---

EDIT: I'm searching for a performant solution that works for heavily layered (think visualizer) situations.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small sample using `globalAlpha`, looks good to me, no residue...
each FadingCircle will have own fade, that will determine how fast it fades and if it goes to 0 or below we do not draw it, seems like an easy solution.
You can add colors, random positions and change it as much as you like to suit your needs.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

class FadingCircle {
  constructor(x, y, radius, fade) {
    this.x = x
    this.y = y
    this.radius = radius
    this.fade = fade
    this.globalAlpha = 1
  }
  draw(ctx) {
    if (this.globalAlpha > 0) {
      ctx.beginPath()
      ctx.globalAlpha = this.globalAlpha
      ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, Math.PI * 2, 0)
      ctx.fill()
      this.globalAlpha -= this.fade
    }
  }
}

let sml = new FadingCircle(40, 50, 20, 0.01)
let med = new FadingCircle(140, 50, 30, 0)
let big = new FadingCircle(100, 50, 50, 0.005)

let animation = () => {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  big.draw(ctx)
  med.draw(ctx)
  sml.draw(ctx)
  requestAnimationFrame(animation);
};
requestAnimationFrame(animation);
```

```html
<canvas width="300" height="120"></canvas>
```

Comment: There are many cases where this could work.  A few issues though: 1. if two things are drawn over each other, they will blend as as they fade (rather than fade the overlay).  2. most real use cases of fading involve more entities and layers than would be efficient in this manner.

Comment: @SephReed Now you are adding things that were not in your original post, the overlap effect is a complex problem you can research Overlapping Shadow Rendering for approaches you can use ... and if you are looking for something efficient that can handle many entities, you should look into a game engine, there are a lot of great open source ones:
https://github.com/collections/javascript-game-engines